# How to remove JS from a page during preprocess D7

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

I'm trying to remove few JS files from one page, which will be called in an Iframe (so no TEMPLATE_js_alter possible because of the if condition).

This code below unset the JS but they are still loaded on the page. It's like I can't save the new list of JS.

Any ideas ?

```
 function theme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
        $scripts = drupal_add_js();
        dsm($scripts);

        if(arg(0) == "account" && arg(1) == "reset"){
            foreach ($scripts as $key => $value) {
                $uri = strrpos($key, 'sites/all');
                if($uri !== FALSE){
                    unset($scripts[$key]);
                }
            }
            $variables['scripts'] = $scripts;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Scripts are output in html.tpl.php, not page.tpl.php so you're just implementing the wrong hook. There's no reason not to use hook_js_alter here though, that would be the best solution

Comment: but it's in a iframe which basically don't send back the arg() of the iframe page but from the parent page, and I couldn't find a way to find my page/form (hook_menu so no nid)

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you mean by that. Having been requested via an iframe makes no difference to how the server generates a page. Unless you specifically make it so. The conditional you have in the preprocess hook will work identically in hook_js_alter

Comment: Oh actually the condition on hook_js_alter works fine! but it doesn't display (dsm) the good arg(), but the one of the previous page calling the iframe. I though I wouldn't be able to get the real arg() but in fact it's working despite the wrong display. Do you know why ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try hook_js_alter and remove it from there:

```
module_hook_js_alter(&$data) {
  dpm($data);
  unset($data['script']);
  dpm($data);
}
```

Comment: but it's in a iframe which basically don't send back the arg() of the iframe page but from the parent page, and I couldn't find a way to find my page/form (hook_menu so no nid)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you really need to use that code in a preprocess function, you should do it in `hook_preprocess_html()` with code similar to the following one.

```
function theme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $scripts = drupal_add_js();

  if (arg(0) == "account" && arg(1) == "reset") {
    foreach ($scripts as $key => $value) {
      if (strrpos($key, 'sites/all') !== FALSE) {
        unset($scripts[$key]);
      }
    }

    drupal_static_reset('drupal_add_js');
    drupal_add_js($scripts);
    $variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();
  }
}
```

`$variables['scripts']` should contain the value returned from `drupal_get_js()`. See [`template_preprocess_html()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_process_html/7).

```
  $variables['head'] = drupal_get_html_head();
  $variables['css'] = drupal_add_css();
  $variables['styles'] = drupal_get_css();
  $variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();
```

I agree with @CLive about first trying to implement [`hook_js_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7), which I expect to work since Drupal doesn't make difference between a page requested with `<iframe src="http://example.com/your/drupal/page" />` and pages requested trough a link, or directly from the user.